# Paginated List not working with the View with multiple model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I used the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to build the ASP.NET Core Web application to help with the Search/sort/pagination. I have the PaginatedList.cs class as suggested in the link to help with Pagination like

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex > 1);
    }}

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
    }}

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

I have a View which uses multiple Model, so created a collection model like below

```
public class CustomerInventoryCollectionDataModel
{
    public Customer CustomerData { get; set; }
    public List<Inventory> Inventorys { get; set; }
}
```

So I want the Pagination for the Inventorys tables on the Index view. So as suggested in the link I am using the the PaginatedList on the view like

```
@model PaginatedList<JAXApp.Models.CustomerInventoryCollectionDataModel>

<div>
<h4>Customer</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        Customer Number
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerData.CustomerNumber)
    </dd>
</d1>

<table class="table">
<thead>...</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Inventorys)
    {
```

It throws error when I am trying to access CustomerData  and Inventorys in the view like above
[image]

`'PaginatedList<CustomerInventoryCollectionDataModel>' does not contain a definition for 'Inventorys' and no accessible extension method 'Inventorys' accepting a first argument of type 'PaginatedList<CustomerInventoryCollectionDataModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

`PaginatedList<CustomerInventoryCollectionDataModel>' does not contain a definition for 'CustomerData' and no accessible extension method 'CustomerData' accepting a first argument of type 'PaginatedList<CustomerInventoryCollectionDataModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

How can have pagination for the Inventorys tables as suggested in the link

Comment: your model is a collection. PaginatedList does not have a property Inventorys. The items inside your collection/model do have that property. Loop through you model and use item.CustomerData.CustomerNumber

Comment: @lordvlad30 I was following the link to build it and I am very newthe Web App development .. Can you help me suggest if I need to changed the PaginatedList class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your View you defined `PaginatedList` as your View model and it doesn't have any property with name `CustomerData` or `Inventorys`.

you can change your code like this:

```
public class CustomerInventoryCollectionDataModel
{
    public Customer CustomerData { get; set; }
    public PaginatedList<Inventory> Inventorys { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
@model JAXApp.Models.CustomerInventoryCollectionDataModel

<div>
<h4>Customer</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        Customer Number
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CustomerData.CustomerNumber)
    </dd>
</d1>

<table class="table">
<thead>...</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Inventorys)
    {
```